# split strings with strtok and then save them error

Tags: c, string, strtok, microprocessors

i Have the following code

```
char inputs []="3,0,23.30,3,30/55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,64,64,64,100,100,100,100,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,55,55,70/1.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1"; 

char parameters[18];

strcpy(parameters,strtok(inputs,"/"));
```

and then some code to transmit my characters through uart and see them at a monitor. when i transmit the inputs i see them fine but when i transmit the parameters i see nothing the string is empty.

i have seen examples for strtok and it uses that code to split strings. I have also tried this kind of code at visual studio and when i print them it shows me the strings fine. Is there any chance that strtok doesn't function well with a microprocessor????

Comment: Which microprocessor are you using, and on which compiler ?

Comment: @slaadvak avr 32 bit UC3c2512c and atmel studio 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with microcontrollers, you have to take care from which memory area you are working on. On software running on a PC, everything is stored and run from the RAM. But, on a flash microcontroller, code is run from flash (also called program memory) while data are processed from RAM (also called data memory).

In the case you are working on, the `inputs` variable is storing an hardcoded character array, which can be const, and we don't know in which area the compiler chose to put it. So, we could rewrite you small program just to make sure that all the data are stored in program data and we will use the "_P" functions to manipulate this data.

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h > // to play in program space

const char inputs PROGMEM []="3,0,23.30,3,30/55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,64,64,64,100,100,100,100,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,55,55,70/1.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1"; // Now, we are sure this is in program memory space

char buffer[200];    // should be long enough to contain a copy of inputs
char parameters[18];

int length = strlen_P(inputs); // Should contains string length of 186 (just to debug)

strcpy_P(buffer,inputs); // Copy the PROGMEM data in data memory space

strcpy(parameters,strtok_P(buffer,"/")); // Parse the data now in data memory space
```

For more info on program space with avr gcc : http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html

Comment: i see. well i have a 32bit avr so there is no such header as avr.pgmspace.h so i will have to search it for a while and then try your code. I will give feedback as soon as i ll do it

Comment: i just used const definition at inputs and ti worked!!thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use strtok much, if at all, but this appears to be the correct way to store the result of strtok() in an char[]:

```
const int NUM_PARAMS = 18;
const int MAX_CHARS = 64;
char parameters[NUM_PARAMS][MAX_CHARS];
char delims[] = "/";
char *result = NULL;
int count = 0;
result = strtok(inputs, delims);
while(result != NULL && count < NUM_PARAMS){
    strncpy(parameters[count++], result, MAX_CHARS);
    result = strtok(NULL, delims);
}
```

or this if you don't want to allocate unnecessary memory for smaller tokens:

```
const int NUM_PARAMS = 18;
char* parameters[NUM_PARAMS];
char delims[] = "/";
char *result = NULL;
int count = 0;
result = strtok(inputs, delims);
while(result != NULL && count < NUM_PARAMS){
    parameters[count] = malloc(strlen(result) + 1); 
    strncpy(parameters[count++], result, MAX_CHARS);
    result = strtok(NULL, delims);
}
```

parameters should now contain all of your tokens.

Comment: @bstar65 well i didn't want to use this kind of code because i don;t have the same sized arrays. i mean after parameters my next token will be about 191 char length so i didn;t want to create a 2d array [3][195] it uses too much memory with no reason. So i tried to do it with different sized arrays

Comment: @arcanavk I made an update that uses malloc for each token so you don't allocate unnecessary memory.  I didn't get a change to test this so please let me know if it doesn't work!

Comment: @bstar65  no neither of your solution works in atmel studio, And in visual studio the first that i tried works

Answer (score 1):

[**`strtok()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) intentionally modifies the source string, replacing tokens with terminators as it goes. There is no reason to store the content in auxiliary storage whatsoever so long as the source string is mutable.

Splitting the string into conjoined constants (which will be assembled by the compiler, so they ultimately will be a single terminated string):

```
char inputs []="3,0,23.30,3,30/"
               "55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,64,64,64,100,100,100,100,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,55,55,70/"
               "1.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1";
```

Clearly the second and third sequences delimited by `'/'` are nowhere *near* 17 chars wide (remember, your copy needs one more place for the terminator, thus only 17 chars can legally be copied).

Unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise, I see no reason you can't simply do this:

```
char *param = strtok(inputs, "/");
while (param != NULL)
{
    // TODO: do something with param...

    // ... then advance to next param
    param = strtok(NULL, "/");
}
```

What you do with `// TODO do something with param...` is up to you. The length of the parameter can be retrieved by `strlen(param)`, for example. You can make a copy, providing you have enough storage space as the destination (in the second and third cases, you *don't* provide enough storage with only an 18-char buffer in your example).

Regardless, remember, `strtok()` *modifies the source* `inputs[]` *array*. If that is not acceptable an alternative would be something like:

```
char *tmp_inputs = strdup(inputs);
if (tmp_inputs != NULL)
{
    char *param = strtok(tmp_inputs, "/");
    while (param != NULL)
    {
        // TODO: do something with param...

        // ... then advance to next param
        param = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }

    // done with copy of inputs. free it.
    free(tmp_inputs);
}
```

There are considerably threading decisions to make as well, the very reason the version of `strtok()` that requires the *caller* (you) to tote around context between calls was invented. See [**`strtok_r()`**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialialize `parameters` that way :

```
char parameters[18] = {'\0'};
```

Thus, it will be initialized with null characters instead of variable values. This is important, because strcpy will try to find a null character to identify the end of the string.

Just to make it clear...
parameters after its initialisation : `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
parameters after strtok : `['3',',','0',',','2','3','.','3','0',',','3',',','3','0',0,0,0,0]`

Comment: There is no reason this is needed. `strcpy` will terminate the string. And `strtok` *replaces* the delimiter found with `0` (that is somewhat the point of the function in the first place).

Comment: Yes you're all rights... in fact, I realize that the OP's code excerpt is working as is when I printf parameters...

Comment: nope it didnt work. And i have used strcpy like this before it showed me no problem. What i don't understand is why this code works on visual studio when i was just doing a test to learn strtok and in my atmel ide it doesn't. And strlen also didn't work on the microprocessor and i had to put the value by its number

Comment: @arcanavk you say that `strlen(inputs)` is not working as well right ? Have you tried with an array with a smaller size, just to see if we're not facing a size issue ?

Comment: @slaadvak yes it not working. Yes i tried it with a 6 char length but it also didn;t work. And everything works fine on visual studio just in my microprocessor there are some problems.

Comment: Which atmel microcontroller are you using ? Are you using AVR Studio ?